# Ruby on Rails: Saving query string parameter value to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, parameters, send

I search google for this question but i did not find any solution for
that.

I want to save parameter value to database. this parameter send by url.

for example:
http://simple-beach-416.heroku.com/code/restserver?fname=cv

I want to save fname value(here "cv") to database.
how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a model for it? This is very vague... but define a model called Fname and give it the attribute "value"

Then...

```
Fname.create(:value => params[:fname])
```

I *think* this is where you're going, yeah?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I generate a controller and a method on that,  and call create model method with parameter:


  def add_item
    Pers1.create(:fname => params[:fn], :lname => params[:ln])
    render :text => "Success!"
  end